# Как передать данные из браузера?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x

У меня есть простенькое расширение для Google Chrome которое получает Url открытой вкладки и выводит его на экран.

```
//manifest.json
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Hello world",
"version": "1.0",
"description" : "This is a simple chrome extention",

"icons":{
    "16": "icons/16.png",
    "32": "icons/32.png",
    "48": "icons/48.png",
    "128": "icons/128.png"
},
"content_scripts" : [
    {
        "matches" : ["<all_urls>"],
        "js" : ["background.js"],
        "run_at" : "document_end"
    }
]
}

//background.js
alert(window.location.href);
```

Можно ли как-нибудь передать этот Url из браузера в Python-скрипт? Или с помощью python-скрипта получить этот Url из браузера?

Comment: Не совсем ясен вопрос - вам нужно просто получить `url` активной вкладки или получить результат-`json` работы расширения?

Comment: Надо получить результат работы расширения

Comment: Поднимайте свой веб-сервер, можно простейший типа Civetweb или встроенный в aiohttp, и отправляйте на него http-запрос. Можно попробовать использовать промежуточные звенья, типа телеграма.